# Xamarin: Scrolling to a position of a ListView when the listview is contained inside of a CarouselViewControl

Tags: android-layout, listview, xamarin.forms, carousel

Is there any way to directly access a listview that is contained within a CarouselViewControl? 
I have a Carousel for the left and right swiping and inside each page, there is a listview. However, since the ListView is contained within the CarouselViewControl, I can't access it directly via code to call the ScrollTo() function nor is the ScrollTo function bindable. I've also tried looping through all of the rendered controls via a FindVisualChildren extension and it appears that when the Carousel renders, it doesn't render the listview as a listview so I don't see any way that I can scroll to a specific vertical position within it.

I'm trying to make an alphabet selector (similar to the one on android's music player) so that when the user clicks a letter, it takes them to that position in the listview. However, it also has to be inside of a carousel view so that it shows a different list when they swipe between the other pages.

Anyone have any ideas if there's any [other] way to do this?

```
<controls:CarouselViewControl x:Name="RecipeList"  Orientation="Horizontal" InterPageSpacing="10" ItemsSource="{Binding ProductList}" 
                              VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" PositionSelected="RecipeList_PositionSelected" 
                              HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
    <controls:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <ListView x:Name="sublist" Margin="5,10,-10,-10" ItemSelected="RecipeList_ItemSelected" IsGroupingEnabled="True" 
                          GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding Key}" ItemsSource="{Binding ProductsList}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never" 
                          SeparatorVisibility="None" HasUnevenRows="True" BackgroundColor="Transparent" SelectedItem="{Binding ScrolledItem}">

                    <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell Height="1">
                                <Label Text="" />
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" MinimumHeightRequest="{StaticResource ImageSize}" 
                                      Padding="15,10,0,0">
                                    <Frame HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="0" Margin="0,5,10,0" CornerRadius="10" 
                                           BackgroundColor="#FCFAF8" BorderColor="#F37623" HasShadow="True">
                                        <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Aspect="AspectFit"/>
                                            <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" RowSpacing="0">
                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <Label Text="{Binding ProductNane}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="Black" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Margin="0,5,0,0"/>
                                                <Image Source="{Binding HeartImage}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Transparent" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" Aspect="AspectFit" Margin="0,5,10,1" >
                                                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="HreatImageClicked"/>
                                                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                                </Image>
                                                <Label Text="{Binding Description}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource StandardLabel}" FontSize="Small" MaxLines="2" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" />
                                                <lv:RatingImage Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ImageDeselect="star_line.png" ImageSelect="yellow_star.png" ImageHeight="12" ImageWidth="12"
                                                   ItemsNumber="5" InitialValue="{Binding Rating}" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="End"
                                                   SpaceBetween="2" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="0,0,2,0" />
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Frame>

                                    <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="RecipeDetailPage" />
                                    </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                                </Grid>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
</controls:CarouselViewControl>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Subclass this listView, so it can access its ItemsSource and so anything like scroll to item, reacting to external bindings. Use x:Reference binding to use parent's binding context and attach to viewModel telling where to scroll etc

Comment: Sorry Nick. I'm not really sure what you mean by sublcass the listview?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/listview

Comment: Okay. I knew that :) I've just subsclassed it and I have everything breaking where it's supposed to be and selecting what it's supposed to be selecting but on the screen, the listview doesn't actually scroll. No errors or anything, just doesn't do anything. Stepping through the code, everything appears to be working right, but it's just not updating the listview scroll position. Is there a way to "refresh" it or someting?

Comment: Not sure how to add my code changes here without editing the whole question. Too many characters for a comment.

Comment: Nevermind. I got it. For some reason (still not yet known) it was calling the constructor of the subclass twice and was changing my private variable to a listview that was in memory rather than the one being displayed. I added a condition to only set the variable if it wasn't already set and viola! Thanks Nick!

Answer (score 0):

> I can't access it directly via code to call the ScrollTo() function nor is the ScrollTo function bindable.

You want to get ListView from CarouselViewControl DataTemplate, I think it is unreasonable, because it is just DataTemplate, I don't find any way to access control in DataTemplate.

So I suggest you can Create an ExtendedScrollView and expose the ScrollTo method into a read only bindable ICommand property. Bind it to your view model corresponding command and use it from there.

You can reuse the control everywhere and it can support any kind of scrolling scenario. You need to create an object to be used a the command parameter that will embed the parameters of ScrollTo, and use it inside the bindable ICommand inside ExtendedScrollView.